# How do I remove a specific bullet point within a ul in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a simple list and all I want to do is remove a specific bullet point (just the icon, not the content within the li) within the `ul`.

I've used first-child to take away the first but I'd like to remove the sixth bullet point!

I could so it inline but I'd prefer to do it with CSS.

How can I do this?

Comment: To clarify by "bullet point" do you mean the whole thing or just the bullet icon?

Comment: Original post edited :)

Comment: Well you have the answers here to cover every scenario possible!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5d4TU/)

You can use the [**nth-child**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector to achieve this.

---

```
li:nth-child(6) {
   list-style-type: none; 
}
```

---

**Edit:**

It now seems you want to hide it for the last child, you can use the last-child selector instead:

[**New jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5d4TU/2/)

```
li:last-child {
   list-style-type: none; 
}
```

---

If you'd like to get either of these working in IE6-8, you could use [**Selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/).

> "Selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes
>   and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8"

nth-child and last-child are some of those supported selectors in Selectivizr.

Comment: Me again. I have many ul's with a different number of li's within. If, let's I have 6 li's (I'd then use your answer) but then on another ul I have 7 li's (so the list-style I want to remove takes away the 6th not the 7th) what would I do then? Does that make any sense at all?!?

Comment: Take a look here: http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/iPhone5.php and scroll down to the Pro's and Con's near the bottom. On this page I used your answer. Now, take a look here: http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/iPhone4S.php On this page (as there are less Pro's and Con's and I use your answer it remove 'Expensive to buy' and not the 'Con's'. Phew!

Comment: No, it's not last-child I'm looking for.

Comment: Haha, sure! Did you look at both pages? On the iPhone 5 page, all is well. On the iPhone 4S page (I've used your suggestion) and as 'Expensive....' is the sixth li it's taken that one away. That's wrong. I want to 7th list-style to be removed. Any clearer?

Comment: @ChrisBrighton Yes, but I don't think you're checking my new jsFiddle I'm posting you with the answer...

Comment: From 7 minutes ago, that's the last-child example. Oh. I don't see it!

Comment: I appreciate all your help but it's not what I'm looking for. Let's say I have two ul's one with 5 li's in and the other with 7 li's in. I want to remove the list-style from the 2nd li from the first list and the 3rd li from the second list. Using last-child won't help.

Comment: @ChrisBrighton So you want the second to last child? http://jsfiddle.net/5d4TU/3/

Comment: Hm. Basically, all I want are the words 'Pro's' and 'Con's' NOT to have a bullet point. However, each 'Verdict List' as I'm calling them have a different amount of li's.

Comment: @ChrisBrighton I can't test from your website though, that's why I'm using jsFiddle. This seems very different from your initial question, now you want to select two elements which are more than 1 space apart which is more complicated..

Comment: Fair enough. I will create a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris Well, I tried my best man, if you actually look at both your questions themselves, I answered them.. hope you find a solution soon anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Use nth-child DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/L8VW4/

This will remove the list item

```
li:nth-child(6) {
   display: none; 
}
```

This will remove only the bullet icon present beside the list item and leave the list item itself in place

```
li:nth-child(6) {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: @Adrift - That was my interpretation as well but on re-reading the question I can see it is ambiguous. By 6th bullet point they might mean both the point and the bullet.