# want to make a swipe menu common for all page of my html,

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I add some code for my swipe menu, the listview went well and can display the grid icon in the listview as mentioned in my code. However, if I want to prevent from redundant code, put the swipt menu as a commond code, the listview will show the bullet point.
anyone know how to solve?

```html
<ul data-role="listview" id="menuListview">
  <li data-icon="grid" id="#Page1"><a href="#Page1">Page1</a></li>
  <li data-icon="grid" id="#Page2" ><a href="#Page2">Page2</a></li>
  <li data-icon="grid" id="Page3" ><a href="#Page3">Page3</a></li>
  <li data-icon="grid" id="Page4"><a href="#Page4">Page4</a></li>
  <li data-icon="grid" id="Page5"><a href="#Page5">Page5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a specific bullet point within a ul in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286921/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-bullet-point-within-a-ul-in-css)